# UICollectionView will not register long press without delay

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am using a UICollectionView within a UIViewRepresentable on an app. I am trying to register a long press gesture on the UICollectionView with a minimum press duration at or very close to 0, but the press keeps on waiting for about 0.5 seconds before the event activates

what I have tried thus far
1: in the makeView function of the UIViewRepresentable setting the delaysContentTouches of the returned UICollectionView to false :
`uiCollectionView.delaysContentTouches = false`

2: setting the delaysTouchesBegan of the LongPressGesture to false as well as setting the minimum press duration to 0 or to 0.001
`lp.delaysTouchesBegan = false`
`lp.minimumPressDuration = 0.0' ///or to 0.001`

3: subclassing UICollectionView and adding the following single method override

```
override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

}
and finally 
4: the same override function override in my subclassed UICollectionViewCell, although to be honest by that point Im clutching at straws.

Anyone any ideas as to how I can get this long press to be instant?

Comment: I think it needs to be delayed. Because how can UICollectionView know that you don't just click on a cell, a single tap or something

Comment: in this case, a single press (what you just pointed out) is a valid interaction - the user presses/taps once , one cell gets selected. The user presses once and holds in place without moving, one cell gets selected. The user presses, holds then drags over multiple cells - then multiple cells get selected. Afterwards my plan is that a subsequent single tap on an already selected cell will deselect it. What Im trying to eliminate is the small delay at the start of that interaction - to give the user instant confirmation where their swipe has started, whether its a tap or a long hold